# how can Add My On Claim on DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth

How can I add my own claim to a user assertion using DotNetOpenAuth as an OpenID Provider?

I need to add some attribute to ClaimsRequest and ClaimsResponse like "UserID".  I added this attribute in both class ClaimsRequest.cs and ClaimsResponse.cs, and when I build DotNetOpenAuth with this change, it works well in VS 2010 but when I publish on iis 7.5 it throws this exception:

> ### Server Error in '/OpenID' Application.
>
> Could not load file or assembly
>   'DotNetOpenAuth.Contracts' or one of
>   its dependencies. Strong name
>   signature could not be verified.  The
>   assembly may have been tampered with,
>   or it was delay signed but not fully
>   signed with the correct private key.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045) 
>   Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not
>   load file or assembly
>   'DotNetOpenAuth.Contracts' or one of
>   its dependencies. Strong name
>   signature could not be verified.  The
>   assembly may have been tampered with,
>   or it was delay signed but not fully
>   signed with the correct private key.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following
>   information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly
>   'DotNetOpenAuth.Contracts' could not
>   be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is
>   turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry
>   value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]
>   (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some
>   performance penalty associated with
>   assembly bind failure logging. To turn
>   this feature off, remove the registry
>   value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load
>   file or assembly
>   'DotNetOpenAuth.Contracts' or one of
>   its dependencies. Strong name
>   signature could not be verified.  The
>   assembly may have been tampered with,
>   or it was delay signed but not fully
>   signed with the correct private key.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)]
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load
>   file or assembly
>   'DotNetOpenAuth.Contracts,
>   Version=3.4.6.11075, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' or
>   one of its dependencies. Strong name
>   signature could not be verified.  The
>   assembly may have been tampered with,
>   or it was delay signed but not fully
>   signed with the correct private key.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)] 
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection,
>   Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +567
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String
>   assemblyString, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
>   +192    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +35
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
>   +118
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could
>   not load file or assembly
>   'DotNetOpenAuth.Contracts,
>   Version=3.4.6.11075, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' or
>   one of its dependencies. Strong name
>   signature could not be verified.  The
>   assembly may have been tampered with,
>   or it was delay signed but not fully
>   signed with the correct private key.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)] 
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
>   +11396867    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +484    System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal()
>   +127    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +334
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods()
>   +280    System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost,
>   IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory,
>   HostingEnvironmentParameters
>   hostingParameters, PolicyLevel
>   policyLevel, Exception
>   appDomainCreationException) +1087
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not
>   load file or assembly
>   'DotNetOpenAuth.Contracts,
>   Version=3.4.6.11075, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' or
>   one of its dependencies. Strong name
>   signature could not be verified.  The
>   assembly may have been tampered with,
>   or it was delay signed but not fully
>   signed with the correct private key.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)] 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +11529072
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +141
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +4784373
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET
>   Version:4.0.30319.1

Answer (score 3):

You should not be adding attributes to the `ClaimsRequest` or `ClaimsResponse` classes as that is the Simple Registration extension and has a fixed set of attributes on it.

Instead, you should use the Attribute Exchange extension, which allows you to set and retrieve arbitrary properties (claims) on it without recompiling the library.  In DotNetOpenAuth this means to use the `FetchRequest` and `FetchResponse` classes to carry your custom claims.

The error you're getting from IIS is because you've improperly "signed" your build of DotNetOpenAuth.  But you shouldn't need to build it yourself if you follow these instructions, so I'll forego the instructions for how to build properly.

Comment: Can you give these instructions on how to build it properly? I'm getting the same error. I just need to add more logging info.